# Painting: Ensure First Brush Stroke is not soaked

Tags: drywall, walls, painting, paint

When using a paintbrush or roller, the first paint dip from the tray contains the most soaked with paint. I usually then spread it on cardboard or plastic to remove the excess (this helps a little). As you use the brush, the paint generally disperses instead of being soaked.

I am doing touch up painting, how do I prevent the first strokes from being soaked for a light touch? Are they any tools or proper methods?

Comment: I find an 18" roller properly loaded works well. If it drips when you hold it over the tray then you have too much paint on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use a paint tray or pot

Use the "high and dry, sloped" area of the paint tray as intended: to "roll out" the roller to remove excess paint.

Use the edge of the paint pot to wipe the brush over and over as needed to squeegee out excess paint.

If you're not getting enough removal, do it more.

If the sloped area is underwater with paint, you overfilled the tray. Of course it will be wetted with paint, a roller just went over it.

Comment: also, how do I squeegee out the paint? Is there a tool?

Comment: @mattsmith5 If the sloped area is underwater with paint, you overfilled the tray. Of course it will be wetted with paint, a roller just went over it.  Try actually painting and this will become more obvious. No replacement for experience. Try using old paint to paint something you don't want (and throw it away).

Comment: hi , do you know the terminology for the black net thing , questin below from bobflux?

Comment: @matt "paint grid" or "metal bucket grid" or "paint can grid".  Does the same thing as the slanted part of a roller tray. You do know, when using a roller tray, not to re-dunk the roller in the paint well, right? Again you seem to be trying to learn "book knowledge" and are focused on "what to buy".  You don't need gadgets, you need experience.  Go make some mistakes lol.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Put one of these in the paint bucket from the shop and roll on it. The extra paint will drop in the bucket.

They are called "paint grid" or "metal bucket grid" or "paint can grid".

Comment: thanks, what are those net thing called?  what is the name? I will try to buy one from Home Depot

Comment: I don't know the English term. I usually get them next to the paint rollers in the shop . There's a metal version to, that does the same thing.

Comment: This is called "paint roller grid" or just "paint grid"